# symmetricds bi-directional not working

Tags: mysql, database, symmetricds

i am using `MySQL` and trying `symmetricds` to replicate the database. I am following [this](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.6/quick-start/html-single/quick-start.html) quick start guide.

I used sample file as it was given in sample folder and just provide my database details in `crop.properties` and `store.properties` file. 
On direction sync is working , like when i insert row in corp database it reflect these changes in `store` database, but when i insert something in store database then i won't sync `corp` database

Could you please help me in resolving issue with database not sync from store to corp?

I was checking the database i can see three trigger with all the corp user database table, But when i check store database then there is not trigger attached to store user database table i have attached image of store database.  store does not showing any trigger (Except `sym_` tables triggers ).

Should is show trigger in client also? Please advise.
image of `corp` database, trigger attached with user table

[image: image of corp database]

image of store database, no trigger attached with user table :-

[image: image of store database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your assumption is correct. the store database should be having triggers on tables that are supposed to be synced from store to corp

check if the corp db is correctly configured. check for sym_trigger, sym_trigger_router and sym_router if there are any config that defines syncing from the store to the corp

Comment: i tried the sample properties file which was there in quick start guide, do i need to change anything thing in those before start the server so i will generate those triggers.

Comment: no, that should be enough. corp triggers are created on startup. then when a store registers it will pull the configuration and by applying it will create triggers on configured tables

Comment: You mean to say when we start store server before that we need to register it?

Comment: By default not, there are two properties in the engine.properties for the corp that are letting it accept automatically registrations (`auto.registration=true`) and sending the initial load (`auto.reload=true`)